# TypeError: __init__ missing 1 required positional argument: 'to', I get this error when I make migrations "python3 manage.py makemigrations"

Tags: python-3.x, django

Python 3.8.10, django version 3.2.9. When I am running the following code: "python3 manage.py makemigrations auth_app" ... I get this error: TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'.
I've checked out everything that says the error and still get the same.This is the whole error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/allfsr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/allfsr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/allfsr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/allfsr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/allfsr/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/allfsr/Documents/C4_WD/BANK/backend_auth/auth_app/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .account import Account
  File "/home/allfsr/Documents/C4_WD/BANK/backend_auth/auth_app/models/account.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Account(models.Model):
  File "/home/allfsr/Documents/C4_WD/BANK/backend_auth/auth_app/models/account.py", line 6, in Account
    user             = models.ForeignKey(related_name='account', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

Comment: You haven't passed a model to the `Account.user` ForeignKey, this argument is required as it's the model the ForeignKey relates to. You probably want to pass `User` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that ? I'm new to django, it's my first framework